# Hanzi for "daigang"?

Tags: characters

[*La société chinoise depuis 1949*](https://www.collectionreperes.com/catalogue/index-La_soci__t___chinoise_depuis_1949-9782348040849.html) by Tania Angeloff (2018; in French) is a book about Chinese society since 1949. The author sometimes uses pinyin without tones to give the Chinese counterparts of some of the terms used in the book.

On page 73 she uses the term *daigang*, which she paraphrases in French as "[personnels] en attente de poste". The French phrase roughly means "waiting for a job or post". Unfortunately, the tones or the Hanzi are not mentioned, and looking up [daigang in MDBG](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?page=worddict&wdrst=0&wdqb=daigang) or [MandarinTools.com](http://www.mandarintools.com/cgi-bin/wordlook.pl?word=daigang&searchtype=pinyin&where=whole&audio=on) did not help.

Does anybody know the Hanzi for this phrase?

Comment: highly recommended: bkrs: 1st (among 3) result for  pinyin "daigang" submission:待岗
 dàigǎng  см.(see) 待工 (see待岗):wait for an appointment; wait for a job

Answer (score 4):

It is 待岗, where 待 means wait and 岗 means job opportunity.

Answer (score 2):

'待岗' /dài gǎng/ is short for '等待岗位' (waiting for post/ job)

等待: /děng **dài**/ to wait

岗位: /**gǎng** wèi/ post; job